# Vercel Postgres + Nuxt Starter template gives 'missing_connection_string' when running local

Tags: javascript, postgresql, nuxt.js, vercel

I want to play around with these new storage features Vercel has added recently, but can't get the Postgress one to work. I used [this template](https://vercel.com/templates/nuxt/postgres-nuxt). It deployed perfectly fine, but when i try to run it locally i'm not sure how to do it. This is what i have done so far:

- Cloned repo to my pc
- Run `npm i`
- Added a .env.local and filled it with the variables that Vercel provided:
  POSTGRES_URL="..."
  POSTGRES_PRISMA_URL="..."
  POSTGRES_URL_NON_POOLING="..."
  POSTGRES_USER="..."
  POSTGRES_HOST="..."
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD="..."
  POSTGRES_DATABASE="..."
- run "npm run serve"

Now i get the page with all the static stuff, but no data from the database. When i visit *localhost:3000/api/get-users* i get the following message:

`"VercelPostgresError - 'missing_connection_string': You did not supply a 'connectionString' and no 'POSTGRES_URL' env var was found."`

**This is what the `get-users.ts` looks like:**

```
import { createPool, sql } from '@vercel/postgres';

async function seed() {
  const createTable = await sql`
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
      id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
      name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      email VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
      image VARCHAR(255),
      "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    );
    `;

  console.log(`Created "users" table`);

  const users = await Promise.all([
    sql`
          INSERT INTO users (name, email, image)
          VALUES ('Guillermo Rauch', 'rauchg@vercel.com', 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1576257734810312704/ucxb4lHy_400x400.jpg')
          ON CONFLICT (email) DO NOTHING;
      `,
    sql`
          INSERT INTO users (name, email, image)
          VALUES ('Lee Robinson', 'lee@vercel.com', 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1587647097670467584/adWRdqQ6_400x400.jpg')
          ON CONFLICT (email) DO NOTHING;
      `,
    sql`
          INSERT INTO users (name, email, image)
          VALUES ('Steven Tey', 'stey@vercel.com', 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1506792347840888834/dS-r50Je_400x400.jpg')
          ON CONFLICT (email) DO NOTHING;
      `,
  ]);
  console.log(`Seeded ${users.length} users`);

  return {
    createTable,
    users,
  };
}
export default defineEventHandler(async () => {
  const startTime = Date.now();
  const db = createPool();
  try {
    const { rows: users } = await db.query('SELECT * FROM users');
    const duration = Date.now() - startTime;
    return {
      users: users,
      duration: duration
    };
  } catch (error) {
    // @ts-ignore
    if (error?.message === `relation "users" does not exist`) {
      console.log(
        "Table does not exist, creating and seeding it with dummy data now..."
      );
      // Table is not created yet
      await seed();
      const { rows: users } = await db.query('SELECT * FROM users');
      const duration = Date.now() - startTime;
      return {
        users: users,
        duration: duration
      };
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  }
});
```

**What i tried to fix this:**
Vercel gives some quickstart codesnippets on their website, one of them was:

```
import pg from 'pg';

const { Pool } = pg;

const pool = new Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.POSTGRES_URL + "?sslmode=require",
})
```

So i thought i might do something like this in my code:

```
  const db = createPool({
    connectionString: process.env.POSTGRES_URL + "?sslmode=require",
  });
```

This gives the following message instead:
`"VercelPostgresError - 'invalid_connection_string': This connection string is meant to be used with a direct connection. Make sure to use a pooled connection string or try createClient() instead."`

Not sure what that means tho. They have [some docs on these errors](https://vercel.com/docs/errors/vercel-postgres-error-codes), but they didn't help me out. Also this [quickstart guide](https://vercel.com/docs/storage/vercel-postgres/quickstart) didn't help me at all.

Can someone here maybe help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently just making it `.env` instead of `.env.local` works.

I have no idea what or why :)

Comment: It is strange! But it works for me too. Thanks for sharing 

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue is that `process.env.POSTGRES_URL` is not available with Vite, the latter [requires](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files) prefixing variables with `VITE_` to access them.

@vercel/postgres [recommends](https://github.com/vercel/storage/tree/main/packages/postgres#a-note-for-vite-users) one of two solutions:

1. Use `dotenv-expand` and enable env variables in *vite.config.js*
2. Import connection url with svelte-kit: `import { POSTGRES_URL } from '$env/static/private'`

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issue. But saving the env variables in a file called .env.development.local solved the issue, but .env.local should also work.

Here is the documentation:
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

In my case, running the site with `vercel dev` is what worked for me, along with a .env file named `.env.development.local`.

I got the idea from this [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/2350) which says:

> This sounds similar to [#2304](https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/2304). Do any of the suggestions in that discussion work for you?
> Another thing to try, if you have not already, is using `vercel dev` instead of other local dev commands like `npm dev`. If any of that gets it working for you, please let me know what worked and which framework you're using so I can share it with the Storage engineering team.