# Vercel postgres storage + Next project having CORS issue

Tags: javascript, postgresql, next.js, vercel

I am interested in experimenting with the latest storage features that Vercel introduced, but I'm having trouble getting the Postgres feature to function. I am uncertain about how this works.

I've followed their docs: [quickstart](https://vercel.com/docs/storage/vercel-postgres/quickstart). Here is what I did so far:

- Create a db and link to my project + I've added a simple table into it directly via vercel platform.
- run `vercel env pull .env.development.local` to retrieve the env created by vercel

I've got that in one of my component:

```
import { createClient, createPool, db, sql } from "@vercel/postgres"

async function test() {
  console.log(process.env.POSTGRES_URL)

  const db = createPool()

  const { rows: users } = await db.query("SELECT * FROM users")
}
```

When the code become executed, either in local or directly on the deployed app, I've got a cors error :

```
Access to fetch at '{POSTGRES_HOST}' from origin 'https://movielog-pied.vercel.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

POSTGRES_HOST being the env given by vercel. I've tried to add cors rights on all method from `*` origin but unsucessfull.

There is also some docs on how to connect but it ain't working for me. Their example is:

```
import { sql } from "@vercel/postgres";

const likes = 100;
const { rows } = await sql`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE likes > ${likes};`;
```

With that i come accross that [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76175232/vercel-postgres-nuxt-starter-template-gives-missing-connection-string-when-r)